# SCReachability error while using paytm Sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, paytm

I integrated `paytm`  in my project but i am getting "**NSReachability error**" because of this code.

[image]

```
[PGServerEnvironment selectServerDialog:self.view completionHandler:^(ServerType type)
     {
         PGTransactionViewController *txnController = [[PGTransactionViewController alloc] initTransactionForOrder:order];
         if (type != eServerTypeNone) {
             txnController.serverType = type;
             txnController.merchant = mc;
             txnController.delegate = self;
             [self showController:txnController];
         }
     }];
```

Thanks for quick response.

Comment: The warning clearly stated that the framework (`systemConfiguration`)should be added by "Add Existing Framework..." in the right-click menu on the project.

Comment: hi Pkc Thanks for quick responce

Comment: hi Pkc Thanks for quick response,can please tell me where is add existing framework beck I'm  new tp iOS

Comment: Project -> build phases

Comment: systemConfiguration.framewok added, still it showing same error.

Comment: Try to add these frameworks:- CFNetwork, Security

Comment: even though getting same error, should i add any lib files.

Comment: ok, its working fine now.

Comment: How you resolve the issue?

Comment: starting i dragged the framework from other project thats why its not targeted to project.

Comment: using my code by default it is showing action sheet to select production server or staging server. i want to avoid action sheet and make it default staging server is it possible.